Can a web-service based on AGPL 3.0 Licensed software demand money for its services?
We are developing a toolkit primarily as a QGIS Plugin (basically a collection of Python code and related scripts that can be run within QGIS). The code is currently still "closed source", but we are leaning towards publishing with AGPL 3.0.
There are plans to establish a web-service that uses builds upon the methods and algorithms contained in the toolkit. It seems clear that any code of this web-service would have to be Open Source as well (copyleft). But is it legitimate to make money with this web-service, i.e. demand a fee for it's usage or demand paid membershibs or the likes?
My assumption is yes, since being build on Open Source doesn't solve any infrastructural costs that come with the web-service. But I want to be sure, not as too scare potential adopter away with AGPL 3.0.

Is the code you have developed entirely your own code, or have you included 3rd party code under OSS licenses, which you have to honor?

Good question - I will have to check that. We didn't knowingly include 3rd party code under OSS licenses into our repository, but we are using Python packages that might be OSS... but I assume to simply "import" them isn't including, it is simply using those packages.

No, importing a package counts as creating a derivative work, so OSS licenses that place restrictions on such use (e.g. all flavours of GPL, unless they have an exception) may impose conditions.  Having said that, as the AGPL is "stronger" than the GPL or LGPL, they are compatible when the derived work is the AGPL (but not the reverse).

Yes, you can charge money for accessing AGPL services.
However, because you are looking at precisely the AGPL (as opposed to the GPL), the network distribution requirements kick in and you must give a full and complete copy of the source code to anyone accessing your services (AGPL Section 13). You may be fine with that, you are providing value by giving reliable hosting and the like.
It's worth noting that the AGPL requirements are not an issue for you until you accept a contribution from a third party under the AGPL - until that point, you can do anything you like with the software.

The first two paragraphs are correct -- in particular, the AGPL does not require you to distribute source to everyone, or to make the service available to everyone, just that whoever has access to the service must also have access to the source.  i.e. you can charge for access to the service, but anyone with a current account (able to access the service) must be able to download the complete source and run their own competing service if they feel so inclined.  Making the source public is a convenient way to ensure that but is not required.

The third paragraph might be correct if the software is entirely an original work, but that is rarely the case.  There will be existing licenses attached to libraries and components being used that will need to be respected.  Some component licenses might require a particular license on derived works, while others might forbid it.
